# The Google Colab page becomes unresponsive during training yolo v3

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am training the yolov3 with my custom images with darknet, everything is going fine but as soon as I start training, after some time of training the page of Google Colab i.e the notebook becomes unresponsive and the browser asks to wait or exit. Why this happens and what is the proper solution for this case.

Comment: Could you check the RAM usage?

Comment: Just a little RAM is used 3 to 4 GB from the given 12 GB of RAM

Comment: Try printing the logs using this ```!cat /var/log/colab-jupyter.log``` to see what is the issue.